# How to send Gmail email using "send email" Rule Node in ThingsBoard Rule Chain?

Tags: email, gmail, rule-engine, thingsboard

I'm using demo ThingsBoard version and I keep getting the same error when "Send Email" node tries to send an email.

Following error occurs:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.sun.mail.util.TraceInputStream.(Ljava/io/InputStream;Lcom/sun/mail/util/MailLogger;)V
>   at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.initStreams(SMTPTransport.java:2265)
>   at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2184)
>   at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:740)
>   at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:291) at
>   org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.connectTransport(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:518)
>   at
>   org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:437)
>   at
>   org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:361)
>   at
>   org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:356)
>   at
>   org.thingsboard.rule.engine.mail.TbSendEmailNode.sendEmail(TbSendEmailNode.java:105)
>   at
>   org.thingsboard.rule.engine.mail.TbSendEmailNode.lambda$onMsg$0(TbSendEmailNode.java:78)
>   at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:125)
>   at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:69)
>   at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:78)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1402)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)